# How can I CREATE new text in tkinter not just make one

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create new text but I don't want to create one text and that's it

For example, if I have a for loop (i do) and need to create new text each time it iterates, the label doesn't work, you can't create new variables in a for loop

This is my code:

```
filenameone = ""
filenametwo = ""
from itertools import zip_longest
import xlrd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
def start():
    global filenameone
    global filenametwo
start()
def browseFilesone():
    print(1)
    global filenameone
    filenameone = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", 
                                          title = "Select a File", 
                                          filetypes = (("Excel (.xlsx)", 
                                                        "*.xlsx*"), 
                                                       ("All files", 
                                                        "*.*")))
    print(filenameone)
def browseFilestwo():
    print(2)
    global filenametwo
    filenametwo = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", 
                                          title = "Select a File", 
                                          filetypes = (("Excel (.xlsx)", 
                                                        "*.xlsx*"), 
                                                       ("All files", 
                                                        "*.*")))
    print(filenametwo)
def check():
    print("check")
    print(filenameone)
    print(filenametwo)
    rb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(filenameone)
    rb2 = xlrd.open_workbook(filenametwo)
    sheet1 = rb1.sheet_by_index(0)
    sheet2 = rb2.sheet_by_index(0)
    pos = 0
    for rownum in range(max(sheet1.nrows, sheet2.nrows)):
        if rownum < sheet1.nrows:
            row_rb1 = sheet1.row_values(rownum)
            row_rb2 = sheet2.row_values(rownum)
            for colnum, (c1, c2) in enumerate(zip_longest(row_rb1, row_rb2)):
                if c1 != c2:
                    print("Row {} Col {} - {} != {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2))
                    pos = pos + 12
                    new_label.configure(text=window.new_label.cget("text").concat("Row {} Col {} - {} is not equal to {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2)))
                    #new_label = Label(text="Row {} Col {} - {} is not equal to {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2))
                #else:
                        #print("Row {} missing".format(rownum+1))

    # Change label contents 
    #label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: "+ filenameone + filenametwo) 
       

                                                                                                   
# Create the root window 
window = Tk() 
new_label = Label(text="")
#my_label = Label(text=)
# Set window title 
window.title('ExcelCompare') 
   
# Set window size 
window.geometry("500x500") 
   
#Set window background color 
window.config(background = "white") 
   
# Create a File Explorer label 
label_file_explorer = Label(window,  
                            text = "ExcelCompare", 
                            width = 100, height = 4,  
                            fg = "blue") 
   
       
button_first = Button(window,  
                        text = "Excel file 1", 
                        command = browseFilesone)
button_second = Button(window,  
                        text = "Excel file 2", 
                        command = browseFilestwo)  
'''
button_exit = Button(window,  
                     text = "Exit", 
                     command = exit)  
   '''
# Grid method is chosen for placing 
# the widgets at respective positions  
# in a table like structure by 
# specifying rows and columns 
label_file_explorer.grid(column = 1, row = 1) 

#my_label.grid(column = 1, row = 11)
button_first.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
button_second.grid(column = 1, row = 7) 
   
#button_exit.grid(column = 1,row = 3)
button_check = Button(window,  
                        text = "Check", 
                        command = check)
button_check.grid(column = 1, row = 9) 
# Let the window wait for any events 
window.mainloop()
```

Where I need help:

I need something that creates new text where the new_label.configure is, inside the for loop.

I put a concat because that's all I know I could do, it supposed to get the current text and add the other stuff but it would be MUCH better if I had something that created new text like in the terminal (print())

oh also i got some help from some websites

Comment: When you say "a new text", do you mean a new `Text` widget, or maybe a new `Label` widget? In this context, "new text" is too vague. Do you want new widgets for each "new text", or would you prefer a single scrollable text widget where you can add multiple lines?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Hi, I prefer a single scrollable text widget, I wanna make it output seperate lines

Comment: What's stopping you, then, from creating a single text widget?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I don't know how to

Comment: @BryanOakley A lot of websites are from a while ago

Comment: tkinter hasn't changed substantiallly in perhaps a decade.

Comment: @BryanOakley really? a lot of the code online gives errors, does that mean the owner did it wrong?

Comment: @Bryanoakley also what should i use

Comment: for the text that adds multiple lines

Comment: @BryanOakley (spelled your user wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widget you want to use is a `Text` widget. I don't know what you want it to look like or where you want to put it, but at a very high level it looks like this:

```
new_label = Text(window, wrap="word")
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window, command=new_label.yview)
new_label.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
...
if c1 != c2:
    message = "Row {} Col {} - {}  is not equal to {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2)
    new_label.insert("end", message+"\n")
```

Comment: window = Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Comment: also I want to add it in the current window, making a new one means I will have two windows

Comment: @user13806962: I copied your own code for `window = Tk()`. That's not my preferred code, I copied yours. I'm not advocating you create a second window. I'm merely showing how to create it in the window you already create. I've removed that line to maybe make it less confusing.

Comment: thank you, but the label isn't appearing on screen, how can i change the coordinates of the label being inserted?

Comment: @user13806962: you have to add a call to `grid` Just like you do for the other widgets.